# Copy all nodes except those with two child elements

Tags: xslt

I've attempted this several ways but I obviously don't understand the match and test elements very well.

This first bit works. It excludes the entire EligibilityBenefit element IF is contains a child element EligibilityorBenefitInformation equal to 'I'.

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template : copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->   
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EligibilityorBenefit[EligibilityorBenefitInformation='I']" />

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is when I attempt to make the selection more restrictive.

I've tried these and they don't work

```
match="EligibilityorBenefit[EligibilityorBenefitInformation='I' and ServiceTypeCode='35']"

match="EligibilityorBenefit[EligibilityorBenefitInformation='I'] and EligibilityorBenefit[ServiceTypeCode='35']"
```

I've also attempted to use just a match like this

```
    <xsl:template match="EligibilityorBenefit">
      <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="EligibilityorBenefitInformation='I' and ServiceTypeCode='35'">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

This is what I have

```
<Eligibility217>
  <Loop2110>
    <EligibilityorBenefit>
      <EligibilityorBenefitInformation>I</EligibilityorBenefitInformation>
      <CoverageLevelCode />
      <ServiceTypeCode>30</ServiceTypeCode>
      <InsuranceTypeCode>EP</InsuranceTypeCode>
    </EligibilityorBenefit>
  </Loop2110>
  <Loop2110>
    <EligibilityorBenefit>
      <EligibilityorBenefitInformation>A</EligibilityorBenefitInformation>
      <CoverageLevelCode>IND</CoverageLevelCode>
      <ServiceTypeCode>33</ServiceTypeCode>
    </EligibilityorBenefit>
    <EligibilityorBenefit>
      <EligibilityorBenefitInformation>I</EligibilityorBenefitInformation>
      <CoverageLevelCode>IND</CoverageLevelCode>
      <ServiceTypeCode>35</ServiceTypeCode>
    </EligibilityorBenefit>
    <Message>
      <MessageText>Specialist</MessageText>
    </Message>
    <Loop2115>
      <Information>
        <CodeListQualifierCode>ZZ</CodeListQualifierCode>
        <IndustryCode>11</IndustryCode>
      </Information>
    </Loop2115>
  </Loop2110>
</Eligibility217>
```

This is what I want

```
<Eligibility217>
  <Loop2110>
    <EligibilityorBenefit>
      <EligibilityorBenefitInformation>I</EligibilityorBenefitInformation>
      <CoverageLevelCode />
      <ServiceTypeCode>30</ServiceTypeCode>
      <InsuranceTypeCode>EP</InsuranceTypeCode>
    </EligibilityorBenefit>
  </Loop2110>
  <Loop2110>
    <EligibilityorBenefit>
      <EligibilityorBenefitInformation>A</EligibilityorBenefitInformation>
      <CoverageLevelCode>IND</CoverageLevelCode>
      <ServiceTypeCode>33</ServiceTypeCode>
    </EligibilityorBenefit>
    <Message>
      <MessageText>Specialist</MessageText>
    </Message>
    <Loop2115>
      <Information>
        <CodeListQualifierCode>ZZ</CodeListQualifierCode>
        <IndustryCode>11</IndustryCode>
      </Information>
    </Loop2115>
  </Loop2110>
</Eligibility217>
```

Comment: In http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8d your first attempt `<xsl:template match="EligibilityorBenefit[EligibilityorBenefitInformation='I' and ServiceTypeCode='35']" />` seems to work.

Comment: I see. It does seem to work. I don't know what to say. Thank you for checking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was unwittingly posted by me in my example of what I had attempted.

For some reason I didn't believe it had worked. After checking it again, I see now that I had the solution from the beginning.

```
match="EligibilityorBenefit[EligibilityorBenefitInformation='I' and ServiceTypeCode='35']"
```